# Remove first part of the string by batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, substring

This is my full path
`U:\temp\Obj\x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def`

I need to get the `\x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def` part from this by removing first part.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If it is always `U:\temp\Obj` that needs to be removed, a simple [string edit/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) will do:

```
C:\>set FOO=U:\temp\Obj\x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def
C:\>set BAR=%FOO:U:\temp\Obj=%
C:\>echo %BAR%
\x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def
```

Comment: is there a way to use `U:\temp\Obj` part inside a variable?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it depending on what the final requirements are. While the result will be the same, it is not the same to remove two folders from the start than to search three folders up. Some samples

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "value=U:\temp\Obj\x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def"

    rem Tokenize and remove elements from the start
    set "newValue="
    for /f "tokens=3,* delims=\:" %%a in ("%value%") do set "newValue=\%%b"
    echo %newValue%

    rem Going backward from the end
    set "newValue="    
    for %%a in ("%value%\..\..\..\..") do set "newValue=%%~fa"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!value:%newValue%=!") do (endlocal & set "newValue=%%a")
    echo %newValue%

    rem Discarding known elements at the start
    set "newValue=\x64%value:*x64=%"
    echo %newValue%

    set "newValue=%value:*\Obj\=\%"
    echo %newValue%
```

Comment: I'm using your last option. how to remove the first back shahs also? So final will be `x64\Debug\XUIBaseHelp\XUIBaseHelp.def`

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya, the code is replacing everything up to `\Obj\ ` with a backslash, so, remove the backslash `set "newValue=%value:*\Obj\=%"`